# Как получить текст под блока при клики на основной div?

Tags: jquery

Хочу кликнуть по div с классом class="bl1"

```js
$('.bl1').click(function(e) {
  var selecttext = $(this);
  document.getElementById('mytextarea').value += $(selecttext).text();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="bl1">
  <div class="title">Тест</div>
  <div class="text">Привет</div>
</div>
<div class="bl1">
  <div class="title">Тест</div>
  <div class="text">Привет</div>
</div>
<div class="bl1">
  <div class="title">Тест</div>
  <div class="text">Привет</div>
</div>
<div class="bl1">
  <div class="title">Тест</div>
  <div class="text">Привет</div>
</div>
<textarea id="mytextarea" required></textarea>
```

И получить то что в

> class="text"

как такое сделать? 
То что получу я просто добавляю в 
Сейчас имею такой код.

Нужно добавить в

> $(this)

еще класс text или как?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$('.bl1').click(function() {
    var div = $(this);
    var text = div.find('.text').val();
    $('#mytextarea').val(text);
})
```

Код не проверял

Comment: Работает спасибо. Только добавление в texarea сделал так  document.getElementById('useracces_chat').value += text;